# Does bias in regression coefficients affect the prediction?

Tags: least-squares, prediction, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff, bias-correction

Goal is to create ols model for out of sample prediction for log(wages). Theory say I could have a sample selection bias. So I choose the heckit method to correct for it. The correction term lambda (also called) inverse mills ratio is not significant in my ols estimation, means no selection bias. Therefore i estimated a model without lambda. Both models were used for out of sample prediction. Prediction with corrections term yield smaller mse than the other model. And i dont understand why?

Comment: Many methods intended to improve generalization explicitly introduce bias in the estimates, I.e ridge and lasso regression. Generalization depends on a balance between bias and variance.

Comment: MasterStudent, your question is quite broad since the types of biases are rather different. Perhaps you could consider posting separate questions for separate types of bias (but I am not entirely sure myself). @MatthewDrury, I think *selection bias* and to an extent also *omitted variable bias* are rather different animals than the bias that is built into an estimator (cannot find a better term for that) to which the notion of *bias-variance trade-off* applies.

Comment: Which bias are you talking about? $\hat \beta - \beta$ or $E(\hat\beta)-\beta$?

Comment: I think if we talkt about selection bias i would say the second one ? Thats exactly the point i dont understand @RichardHardy. Does the bias of a regression coefficent affect the prediction because of higher mse and do i get a better prediction if i correct it

Comment: @MasterStudent1992, it depends on the type of bias, which is why I suggested narrowing down on that.

Comment: i mean sample selection bias @RichardHardy

Comment: @RichardHardy You are, of course, correct.  I think the point about introducing bias in the coefficients is valid, but comparison the the bias in the tradeoff probably isnt.

Comment: @RichardHardy Maybe more informations about my problem will help to understand my question /problem.Goal is to create ols model for out of sample prediction for log(wages). Theory say I could have a sample selection bias. So I choose the heckit method to correct for it.  The correction term lambda (also called) inverse mills ratio is not significant in my ols estimation, means no selection bias. Therefore i estimated a model without lambda. Both models were used for out of sample prediction. Prediction with corrections term yield smaller mse than the other model. And i dont understand why?

Comment: @MasterStudent1992, why not include the information from your last comment into the post by editing it into a well-defined, concrete and detailed problem? If your actual question is that concrete, this would help. But if your actual question is as broad as posed, then I stand by my first comment.

Comment: @RichardHardy  sry i edited my question now

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about :) And since I do not know enough about "heckit", I will have to leave this for the others.